# Me prodrian decir que tengo mal. mi metodo corre a medias

Tags: java, sqlite

este es el metodo y solo corre hasta la creacion de **myProducts** el cursor y lo demas no lo realiza. alguien me podria decir que tengo mal muchas gracias.

```
public List<Product> getProducts() throws SQLException
{
    String[] columns = new String[]{"_id","name","barcode","salePrice","numProvider","productImage"};

    Log.i(TAG,"Fetching the videos from the database for ListView");

    List<Product> myProducts = new ArrayList<Product>();
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DatabaseContents.TABLE_PRODUCT_CATALOG.toString(),columns,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    Log.i(TAG,"Cursor created. Looping through rows");
    int prodIndex = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
    int prodIndexName = c.getColumnIndex("name");
    int prodIndexBarcode = c.getColumnIndex("barcode");
    int prodIndexSalePrice = c.getColumnIndex("salePrice");
    int prodIndexNumProvider= c.getColumnIndex("numProvider");
    int prodIndexProductImage = c.getColumnIndex("productImage");



    for (c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
    {
        myProducts.add(new Product(c.getInt(prodIndex),c.getString(prodIndexName),
                c.getString(prodIndexBarcode),c.getDouble(prodIndexSalePrice),
                c.getInt(prodIndexNumProvider),c.getString(prodIndexProductImage)));

        Log.i(TAG,"Adding video name: "+ c.getString(prodIndex));
    }

    Log.i(TAG,"Finished adding items to videos class");
    return myProducts;

}
```

Comment: puedes probar cambiando ArrayList<> por List<>?

Comment: Me dice que List<> es abstracta y no me deja mas que con ArrayList<>

Comment: Te lanza alguna excepcion?

Comment: si de echo como solo tenia puesto el tag no vi lo demas ya arregle la excepciones anteriores pero ahora solo me sale esto   **E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 68 rows, 5 columns.**

Comment: estas seguro que esos son los nombres de columnas? el api de `getColumnIndex()` retorna -1 si la columna no existe.

Comment: gracias si tenia uno mal era unit_price y tenia saleprice gracias